# Is there a way to get NTH_VALUE with a variable N? (SQL - BigQuery)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

With a Bigquery table as such:

```
{"name": "parent_id", "type": "STRING", "mode": "REQUIRED"},
{"name": "parent_x", "type": "INTEGER", "mode": "REQUIRED"},
{"name": "thing_id", "type": "STRING", "mode": "REQUIRED"},
{"name": "created_at", "type": "TIMESTAMP", "mode": "NULLABLE"}
```

Assuming we have one row per "thing_id" with an associated "created_at"

I'm trying to fetch, for each parent id, the Nth "created_at" where the Nth "thing_id" is registered in my table.

I can use NTH_VALUE() but I want my N to be variable based on parent_x, more specifically I want the MIN("literal integer", parent_x) to be N. The problem is that NTH_VALUE() only accepts a literal or query parameter.

How could I get around this?

The result table I'm looking for is:

```
{"name": "parent_id", "type": "STRING", "mode": "REQUIRED"},
{"name": "nth_created_at", "type": "TIMESTAMP", "mode": "NULLABLE"}
```

Comment: I'm a little baffled by your data model.  Can you provide sample data in a *tabular text* format?

Comment: @GordonLinoff row example:

{"user_id": "John","max_friends": 10, "friend_id": "Alice", "became_friends_at": "01-01-2020"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `row_number()` and a window `min()` as follows:

```
select parent_id, created_at nth_created_at
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by parent_id order by created_at) rn,
        min(parent_x) over(partition by parent_id) tn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = tn
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is probably `row_number()`:

```
select t.* except (seqnum)
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by parent_x order by timestamp) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: @JurgenPalsma . . . I noticed that you unaccepted this answer.  Is there something wrong with it?